# Error creating notebook: no lines available in input

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

When trying to Preview a simple notebook in RStudio, I am getting the following error in the top of the source pane and no nb.html file is created:

> "Error creating notebook: no lines available in input"

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

```
> sessionInfo(package = NULL)

R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] backports_1.0.5 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.3.3     base64enc_0.1-3 yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.12    stringi_1.1.3   rmarkdown_1.8   knitr_1.17     
[12] stringr_1.2.0   digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10
```

---

```
> RStudio.Version()

$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.0.153’
```

Comment: After updating RStudio the problem does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to replicate the exact error but you could try writing the output  html notebook in same line.

```
---

title: "R Notebook"

output: html_notebook: default

  html_document: default

---
```

Comment: I replaced the header and got the following message: _Error creating notebook: Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context_

Comment: Can you try using only one output type.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by opening a new Notebook, copying the contents of my original, error-ing Notebook there, and then overwriting the original Notebook. The error presented, for me, after I moved a folder containing all the files associated with this project to a new location.